# Update Server Connection Issue

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, device-firmware

I Have bought Galaxy Sl - GT I9003 , two days back. 
*Region: India*

I have Android

**Firmware Version: 2.2.1 , BuildNumber: FROYO.DDKF1**

When vere I try to to update the firmware OTA,it gives me message "Connection failed", even if the connection is working for other applications.

And when I try to upgrade from Kies, it shows that, It is the latest firmware available, which is certainly not.

How to upgrade the build - firmware for my device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kies: Firmware can not be upgraded?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16115/kies-firmware-can-not-be-upgraded)

Answer (score -1):

Don't bother using Kies or OTA to update your phone. If you do, you will probably update it in the next decade. (I am curious if OTA worked in someone...)

Just find an appropriate ROM for your phone from a trusted forum (eg XDA) and flash it using ODIN.

Comment: does it violate the warranty?

Comment: Yes, if you flash the phone without using Kies warranty is gone...