# Kies: Firmware can not be upgraded?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-kies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Samsung Kies: 'This version of the device can not be updated'. Never?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/samsung-kies-this-version-of-the-device-can-not-be-updated-never)

Have Galaxy SL (GT I9003). Had given mobile to Samsung service center for upgrade to Android 2.3, stupids installed Android 2.2 (Froyo) again. And now my Kies, give message that

"This Firmware can not be updated". Is it because of wrong Kies version or the issue is with OS install itself?

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2):

Kies can and do say that which is quite annoying, due to different regions and the roll outs, some go by carriers as in comes with carrier branding, others by actual region. Its frustrating - I know! :D

Go to [samfirmware](http://www.samfirmware.com), and use odin to flash it yourself if that's what you want to do.

Don't trust Kies in respect to flashing. :) The necessary tools are available on that site if you want to go down the unofficial route.

If you're on Linux, use [Heimdall](http://code.google.com/p/heimdall-one-click/) which is a lot more safer than Kies and is cross-platform friendly.

The onus is on you to read, read, research and more reading if you want to do this by yourself :)

***Caveat Emptor:*** No virtual machines (virtualbox/vmware) with windows running Kies in there - otherwise your handset is a nice paperweight!

Answer (score 1):

See this previous question [Samsung Kies: 'This version of the device can not be updated'](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11872). This message means that there is no upgrade currently available via Kies for your device.

Even if an upgrade has been released for your model in some countries, or even in your country on other phone networks, it still needs to be checked and authorised by your phone network before it will appear as an available upgrade in Kies.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a 2.3 image that you know works on the device, you could use Heimdall to put it on the device.

This would come with the reasonable assumption that if you do this, your warranty is toast.