# Device upgrade issue via Samsung Kies

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-sl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kies: Firmware can not be upgraded?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16115/kies-firmware-can-not-be-upgraded)

Device: Galaxy SL (GT I9003)
I had fresh install from Samsung Service center for Android. They again installed Android 2.2. And now the Kies is saying,

> Your device does not support software upgrading via Kies. Current
>   Firmware Version:  I9003DDKF1/I9003ODDKA6/I9003DDKA5/I9003DDKF1

I stay in India. google search suggests that 2.3.5 update is available. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Whether an update is available via doesn't just depend on which country you're in, it also depends which phone network you're on. If your phone network hasn't authorised the update yet, then it won't be avaialable via Kies.

Comment: @GAThrawn yes the update is available for India. Need to check if is updated for Vodafone or not.

Comment: @GAThrawn have verified with Vodafone.. it is not regulated by Vodfone or anyothr service providers. So its at Samsung end only